# jQuery is canceling the default event operation for a hyperlink

Tags: jquery, events, hash, click, default

I have assigned a .click() handler to an anchor element with jQuery to create an animating effect. The link changes the hash, which is then handled by an AJAX system. The problem is, when I assign the .click() event function, the hash no longer changes automatically. I can manually change it with document.location.hash = "hash", but Firefox doesn't seem to be a fan of that. It works but behaves oddly when I load the page from my history.

Has anyone else encountered a problem like this?

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>

$('a[href="#test"]').click(function(){
 $(this).doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Is `doSomething()` throwing an error? Also, you can just using single quotes rather than escaping the double quotes inside your selector.

Comment: $(this).doSomething(); how come you are calling function like this??

Comment: ...also, you're missing a close paren and a semicolon. Is that an error in your real code, too?

Comment: john , if possible create a jsfiddle or post the complete code ,it will be easy for us to debug.

Comment: If the `a` has any ancestors with a `click` handler bound, make sure they don't `return false;` or call `event.preventDefault()`. Also, please post actual code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: To demonstrate what @patrick's talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/tCZPG/1/

Comment: Check out the JSFiddle. Right-click the Result frame, choose This Frame > Show only this frame (Firefox). Then click the link and you'll see that the anchor is not affected.

I was simplifying my code for demonstrative purposes. My application does not throw any errors in the bug console, but it is considerably more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question again. It turns out I was only confusing myself. It is true that an ancestor element was assigned the click() event rather than the anchor itself. When I changed the event to reflect the anchor instead, I got nothing. Then I realized that the anchor was actually 1x1 dimensions. After re-CSS'ing it, the anchor is now the appropriate size of the list element and everything works properly.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of your actual code try something like this

```
<a href="#test" class="sample">Test</a>

$(".sample").click(function()
{
  alert("href clicked"); // do your animation here
  return false;
}
```